# Android Google Maps v2 - Updating Markers (Issues with Z-Index and WindowsAdapter State)

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm upgrading an existing transportation app from `MapView` to GoogleMap v2.  There are 2 core requirements I have, but moving from Overlays to Markers is introducing the following issues:

**REQUIREMENT 1)** - The map needs to seed an initial layer of fixed position markers.  Then an additional layer of markers to depict the location of vehicles.  The vehicles should always render on top of the station locations if they have the same `LatLng`.

Using Overlays in `MapView`, the Z-Index could be controlled by manipulating the order of the methods that generate the Overlays, this works perfectly:

```
this.GenerateStations();  //Renders a base of Station Overlays
this.GenerateVehicles();  //Renders vehicles on-top of Station Overlays
```

However, when working with the GoogleMap v2, it appears the Map is rendering all the markers randomly regardless of the order each marker instance is created and added.  **Is this an accepted deficiency of the map or are there workarounds?**

**REQUIREMENT 2)** - Each marker implements a `InfoWindowAdapter` to display information about the marker.  On a background thread, the vehicle marker's location and icon are updated every second, the icon needs to change if it's `LatLng` is the same as a Station marker `LatLng`.  The problem is, if I update the marker's Position or Snippet the `InfoWindowAdapter` moves location along with the icon, but when I update the `setIcon` property, I lose the `InfoWindowAdapter`:

```
//This works perfectly, InfoWindowAdapter snippet updates too
vMarker.setPosition(vehicleLatLng);
vMarker.setSnippet(vehicleSnippet);

//Causes the InfoWindowAdapter to disappear 
vMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(imageResource));
```

It appears when setIcon is called, the marker is destroyed and rebuilt.  **Is there another way to update the marker's icon w/out having to lose state with the `InfoWindowAdapter`?**

Answer (score 3):

> it appears the Map is rendering all the markers randomly

No. The markers are rendered from the top of the screen to the bottom, so ordered by current y value.

Have you tried calling `showInfoWindow` after setting the icon?

```
vMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(imageResource));
vMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

**Edit:** or

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        vMarker.showInfoWindow();
    }
});
```

Your idea from comment under Marcin's answer is very reasonable. Kind of specialized clustering.

About the disappearing info window after `setIcon`: I have reported that just after they released a version with this function. You may want to comment on that here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5419

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the order in which markers are generated.

Also, `showInfoWindow()` didn't yield the desired result, Thanks for the ticket link to Google, I posted my issue.

Comment: @CampbellGolf What if you do that in a posted `Runnable`? I know this might be unacceptable because of a blink, but maybe better than nothing. See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when working with the GoogleMap v2, it appears the Map is
>   rendering all the markers randomly regardless of the order each marker
>   instance is created and added. Is this an accepted deficiency of the
>   map or are there workarounds?

There's no control over markers nor the order they are rendered.

Comment: Thanks,  I guess I could do the following as a workaround:  Create a new set of vehicle icons that have a graphic that indicates it's at the station when the LatLng are equal, then Hide the Station icon until the vehicle moves.

But, that means I still have to setIcon on the Vehicle, which causes the second issue I mentioned.  I'm still researching... thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I've got a custom marker which indicates the current location and other marker for pois.

If you add the marker in a given order, first the current position then the pois, the ordering of the marker on the map is correct. The poi markers are above the current position marker.

My code looks then like this:

```
map.clear();
map.addMarker(currentPosition)
for (MarkerOptions poi : poiMarkerOptions) {
     map.addMarker(poi);
}
```